# Elasticsearch filter buckets on score in (or after) aggs

Tags: elasticsearch

ES 7.17.0

We have an index w/ documents comprised of two simple fields - `uid` and `person`.  One `uid` can have many documents, with differing person names.

I have the following query which first finds documents with persons close to name "John Smith", and returns the top-scoring hit from each `uid`, then sorts them in descending order by score:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "person": "John Smith"
        }
    },
    "rescore": {
        "query": {
            "rescore_query": {
                "function_score": {
                    "pair_score": {
                        "field": "person",
                        "query_name": {
                            "data": "John Smith"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "query_weight": 0.0,
            "rescore_query_weight": 1.0
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "top-uids": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "uid"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_uids_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "_score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FYI the `pair_score` function in `rescore` is a custom scorer which normalizes the score, and it's mainly irrelevant to the question - to reproduce my query, you can use any rescore clause.

So again, this query returns the top-scored hit from each `uid` and then sorts those in descending order.  But it returns the top hit of *every* `uid` in the index, whereas I need to filter out all results that have a `_score` below x.  Is there something I can add to the `aggs` clause to accomplish this?

For an additional visual, here is an example of a results set with three results.  The idea would be to put something additional in the `aggs` query (or even after the `aggs` if that works) that says only return hits with a `_score` greater than 0.98.  In that case, this results set would only have the first bucket included:

```
{
    "took": 46,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 8,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "top-uids": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": 1,
                    "doc_count": 5,
                    "top_uids_hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 5,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 1.0,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "test",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "2",
                                    "_score": 1.0,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uid": 1,
                                        "person": {
                                            "data": "John Smith"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 3,
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "top_uids_hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.97371185,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "test",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "17",
                                    "_score": 0.97371185,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uid": 3,
                                        "person": {
                                            "data": "Johnathan Smith"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": 2,
                    "doc_count": 1,
                    "top_uids_hits": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 1,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": 0.41064638,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "test",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "14",
                                    "_score": 0.41064638,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "uid": 2,
                                        "person": {
                                            "data": "Kevin Smith"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And as I look at it now - filtering on `max_score` would also work, if it's easier to accomplish it that way.

**EDIT 1:** It seems the `Bucket Selector Aggregation` functionality is meant to accomplish what I'm looking to do, but it unfortunately does not appear that there is any way to access the `_score` from within a Bucket Selector query.

Comment: Have you tried this?: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-min-score

Comment: Yes I already explored `min_score`- unfortunately `min_score` does not work with `rescore`.